# Mura tag/page content rendered backwards

Tags: coldfusion, mura

**hi** guys,

I'm having bit of an issue with a Mura tag, I don't really use a lot of them but I have one in a page with some content underneath it but no matter what I do it renders below any content entered beneath it.

Is this normal? Is there a work around?

Comment: No, it's not normal. The Mura tag works similar to cfinclude. Output appears where you include it. I suspect that you have rather a HTML/CSS problem, than a Mura problem. Check your HTML source to see where the output actually shows up.

Comment: It appears I've fixed it. I restarted my server and it seemed to fix it, very odd. Could you paste your answer into an actual answer so I can resolve this question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not normal. The Mura tag works similar to cfinclude. Output appears where you include it. I suspect that you have rather a HTML/CSS problem, than a Mura problem. Check your HTML source to see where the output actually shows up.